# Intel Wireless 8260 slow

Tags: debian, wifi, systemd, iwlwifi

I've a PC with an Intel Wireless 8260 running Debian Unstable. `networking.service` slows the startup (with `systemd`) down with 1 minute and ~5 seconds. I'm running version `4.8.15-2` of the Linux kernel with version `20161130-2` of the `iwlwifi` firmware. After my system has finally started up, the internet is slow and I've to run `sudo iw dev wlan set power_save off` to make the speed acceptable, but still not the full speed I get on my cheap Windows laptop. The output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` is:

```
[    4.668210] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.681311] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode (-2)
[    4.681313] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.681326] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode (-2)
[    4.681327] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.695991] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
[    4.696663] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.732100] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    4.734471] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.735424] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.897671] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   66.833134] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   66.833550] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   66.972299] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   66.972727] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

The output of `sudo iwconfig wlan0` is:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VFNL-DE1BA0"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: 00:1D:AA:DE:1B:A0   
          Bit Rate=270 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:23   Missed beacon:0
```

How can I make my system startup fast and get the full speed of my internet?

Comment: This could be related to the following bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190831 See also https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/51271

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1319630) filed against Ubuntu a few years back that said

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Would help regain the performance by enabling aggressive tx
You will need to reboot or unload and load iwlwifi to see the change

Comment: I had the same thing on deepin linux and now it's resolved. Thanks again!